# Java: Subtract '0' from char to get an int... why does this work?

Tags: java

This works fine:

```
int foo = bar.charAt(1) - '0';
```

Yet this doesn't - because bar.charAt(x) returns a char:

```
int foo = bar.charAt(1);
```

It seems that subtracting '0' from the char is casting it to an integer.

Why, or how,  does subtracting the string '0' (or is it a char?) convert another char in to an integer?

Comment: Don't make the mistake of thinking that  `'0' == 0`.  In reality, `'0' == 48`.

Comment: *click* Ah, now it makes perfect sense! If only you'd put that as an answer and pointed me to http://www.cs.utk.edu/~pham/ascii_table.jpg

Comment: this implicit cast doesn't return the decimal representation of the char, as @MarkPeters pointed, so if for example bar.charAt(1) returns 'A', which dec representation is 65, int foo will be 17, 'A' - '0' = 65 - 48 = 17 and not 65.

Comment: This trick is being used in a lot of questions in Leetcode, but I don't see anyone asked about how this trick works for Leetcode questions.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

That's a clever trick. char's are actually of the same type / length as shorts. Now when you have a char that represents a ASCII/unicode digit (like '1'), and you subtract the smallest possible ASCII/unicode digit from it (e.g. '0'), then you'll be left with the digit's corresponding value (hence, 1)

Because char is the same as short (although, an unsigned short), you can safely cast it to an int. And the casting is always done automatically if arithmetics are involved

Comment: shorts can have negative values, char doesn't. Also is not ASCII but unicode ( small but important difference ) : try `int y = '\uffff' - '\ufffe';`

Comment: You're right. For digits, ASCII and Unicode codes happen to coincide, that's why I thought of ASCII first

Comment: That's great. I did need Mark Peter's comment to make me realise that by 'corresponding value' you mean I'm actually subtracting 48 from 49-57. Also, the error I was getting was really an array out of bounds exception so perhaps my question's misleading in saying the first example "doesn't work". Thanks! :)

Comment: To be clear, a `char` isn't considered a subtype of `short` in Java... your answer kind of makes it sound like it is. `char` and `short` are both direct subtypes of `int`. Also, "casting" is done automatically between any type and any type that is considered a supertype of it regardless of whether arithmetic is involved.

Answer (score 17):

This is an old ASCII trick which will work for any encoding that lines the digits '0' through '9' sequentially starting at '0'.  In Ascii,
'0' is a character with value 0x30 and '9' is 0x39.
Basically,
if you have a character that is a digit,
subtracting '0' "converts" it to it's digit value.

I have to disagree with @Lukas Eder and suggest that it is a terrible trick;
because the intent of this action aproaches 0% obvious
from code.
If you are using Java and have a `String`
that contains digits and you want to convert said `String` to an `int`
I suggest that you use
`Integer.parseInt(yourString);`.

This technique has the benifit of being obvious to the future maintenance programmer.

Comment: it's a clever trick. and clever is always a bad thing. it's the opposite of elegant :-)

Answer (score 3):

`'0'` is a char too.  It turns out, the characters in Java have a unicode (UTF-16) value. When you use the `-` operator with characters Java performs the operation with the integer values.

For instance,  `int x = 'A' - '0';// x = 17`

Comment: It doesn't complain at all.  You can do `int y = s.charAt(1)` just fine, without compile or runtime error (assuming `s` has two+ characters).  I think the OP was confused as to why it didn't return the same result.

Comment: @Bart: UTF-16 is an encoding format for unicode, but yes you're right.

Comment: @Mark: I know, but for characters above unicode point 65k, (at least) two UTF-16 char's are used

Comment: You chose a great example to illustrate to limited usefulness of character arithmetic.

Comment: With above example , I get ```jshell> int x = '0' - 'A'
x ==> -17```.

Answer (score 1):

`char`s are converted to `int` implicitly:

```
   public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
     String bar = "abc";
     int foo = bar.charAt(1) - '0';
     int foob = bar.charAt(1);
     System.err.println("foo = " + foo + "   foob = " + foob);
   }
```

output: `foo = 50   foob = 98`.

Maybe you put two `int foo ...` and this is because it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The following code works perfectly fine!

```
int foo = bar.charAt(1);
```

Similar to reference types, any Java primitive can be assigned without casting to another primitive of a type it is considered a subtype of. The subtyping rules for primitives are given by [JLS section 4.10.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.1). `char` is considered a subtype of `int`, so any `char` may be assigned to an `int`.

Comment: Are you sure? ```String s = "9"; int n = s.charAt(0);  System.out.println(n);``` returns 57

Answer (score 1):

Your code may compile without error & run without throwing an exception, but converting between char's & int's is bad practice. First, it makes the code confusing, leading to maintenance headaches down the road. Second, clever "tricks" can prevent compilers from optimizing the byte code. One of the best ways to get **fast** code is to write **dumb** code (i.e., not **clever** code).

Answer (score 0):

Because in Java if you do not specify a type indicator with a number then it assumes Integer.
What I mean by that, if you want to set a Long value, it would need to be 0L.

Performing a numerical operation on two different numerics, the result takes the larger. Hence, a char (which is a numerical value) minus an integer, results in an integer.

You will find that this works also

```
long val = bar.charAt(1) - 0L;
```

Comment: @Lukas it won't, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your second snipped should work fine though:

```
int foo = bar.charAt(1);
```

A `char`, just like a `short` or `byte`, will always be silently cast to `int` if needed.

This will compile just fine: `int i = 'c';`

Comment: Not saying it is, just that you don't need to explicitly cast `char` to `int`, so it's not clear why searbe would need the subtraction.

Comment: nah, if i have a "char c=bar.charAt(1); //c=1;"  then "int foo=c;"  foo will be 49 not 1.      . So subtracting  "int foo=c-'0';  returns 1. :)  because 49-48=1

Answer (score 0):

I will echo what @Mark Peters has said above in case people overlook his comment.

As I quote:
"
Don't make the mistake of thinking that '0' == 0. In reality, '0' == 48
"

Answer (score 0):

'5' has the int value of 53

if we write '5'-'0' it evaluates to 53-48, or the int 5

if we write char c = 'B'+32; then c stores 'b'

'b' = 98.

Please refer ASCII chart
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii