# generating a binary sequence

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, binary-operators

I need to generate a binary sequence of keys where each key is of length 'x',and each key is generated by a specific operation on the previous key.
So assuming the key length to be 3,I should be able to generate a sequence as(illustration):

```
001 010 100 011 .....
```

Each key has to be derived by some bit operation on the previous key,till we have exhausted all possible permutations for that specific key length.
Since I am a newbie on bit operations  - is this a possible operation;and how do we generate this sequence for any given length.
I would prefer an example in java - but the idea is to understand the logic and the specific oepration.

Comment: Just start with all zeroes, stop on all ones, and add one each time.

Comment: Java has bitwise operators (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: I get the idea now  - thanks.So it goes 000 + 1=>001 + 1=>010 + 1.... till we reach 111. A java function will help  ,since this is not what I do often.

Comment: I think this is what will help me achieve what I needed  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548586/adding-binary-numbers.

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: This seems to be hinting very strongly at an [LFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look for pseudo-random generators if the progression has to be a fixed bit operation. You might be interested in grey codes too.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches in Java:

#### Iterative:

Start from `0` to `2^length` and convert each number to binary string padded with zeroes in front.

```
public static List<String> binarySequence(final int length) {
    final int noOfItems = 1 << length;
    final List<String> sequences = new ArrayList<>(noOfItems);
    final String format = "%" + length + "s";
    for (int num = 0; num < noOfItems; num++) {
        final String binary = String.format(format,
                Integer.toBinaryString(num)).replace(' ', '0');
        sequences.add(binary);
    }
    return sequences;
}
```

#### Recursive:

Base case (length 1), Only two values: `0` and `1`. For `length > 1`, prepend `0` and `1` to the sequences from previous recursion. For example, for length of 2, prepending `0` and `1` to the previous recursion output(`0, 1`): `00, 01, 10, 11`.

```
public static List<String> binarySequenceRecur(final int length) {
    final List<String> sequences;
    if (length <= 1) {
        sequences = Arrays.asList("0", "1");
    } else {
        final List<String> prevSequences = binarySequence(length - 1);
        final LinkedList<String> seqs = new LinkedList<>();
        for (final String seq: prevSequences) {
            seqs.addLast("0" + seq);
        }
        for (final String seq: prevSequences) {
            seqs.addLast("1" + seq);
        }
        sequences = seqs;
    }
    return sequences;
}
```