# How to get the OR operation result of binary represented strings?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, binary

I have two strings in the following format:

```
"11010"
"00101"
```

Both are binary representations. I want to **OR** these numbers and get the result as follows:

```
"11111"
```

Any idea on how to get it done using Java?

Upadte:

This is not a duplicate of mentioned question. I am performing OR operator on binary number represented in String format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548586/adding-binary-numbers

Comment: You need to write some code.  There is so many ways you could do this.  I suggest you use a loop and build a new string.

Comment: Convert them to int, use binary operators, convert result back to binary string. `Integer.parseInt(val,radix)` `Integer.toString(val,radix)` can be helpful.

Comment: How long will they be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Integer.parse method

```
int x1 = Integer.parseInt("11010", 2);
int x2 = Integer.parseInt("00101", 2);
int val = x1 | x2;
String binOr = Integer.toBinaryString(val);
```

Comment: With different input this can make the resulting string shorter than the input, by dropping leading zeroes. (that's not wrong, just something to be aware of)

Answer (score 1):

There is so many obvious ways, such as converting to a BigInteger, or string manipulation but this is a less obvious one, which of course you cannot pass of as your own homework, but you might learn something.

```
public static String or(String a, String b) {
    assert a.length() == b.length();
    char[] ac = a.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < ac.length; i++)
        ac[i] |= b.charAt(i);
    return new String(ac);
}
```

I leave it as an exercise for you to work out why this works. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this by using the Integer class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // "11010" "00101"

    // 1. parse the strings to integer
    final int nibble1 = Integer.parseInt("11010", 2);
    final int nibble2 = Integer.parseInt("00101", 2);
    // 2. make the bitwise operation and bulk the result in the int result
    final int result = nibble1 | nibble2;
    // print the result as integer
    System.out.println(result);
    // or print it as binary
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result));
}
```