# how can i use biginteger to operate with binaries values

Tags: java, binary, biginteger

I'm working with java, and I'm trying to play with numbers in different bases (2,8 and 10).

So, I'm asking this question to change a binary number in string format into number in base 10

such as 11000000101010000000000000111111/base 2

I tried Integer.parseInt(str,radix) however I got errors. exepetion ""Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11000000101010000000000000111111" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548586/adding-binary-numbers

Comment: i've used `Integer.parseInt()` it does not work any other ideas

Comment: The answer that I pointed you not only just parses Integer, it parses specifying a radix.

Comment: It uses the same algorithm explained by Kevin Esche.

Comment: thank you too @RubioRic, yes it uses radix but when i used Integer.parseInt(str,radix) the SE throws me this exepetion ""Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11000000101010000000000000111111"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) ""                              so i asked this question

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this is off-topic. It may be a duplicate, though, of the question linked to by RubioRic.

Answer (score 5):

BigInteger provides a `BigInteger(String,int)` constructor, where you can define the `radix`. You could simply create two instances, one for the initial value, and one for the `1`. Further on you´d just need to use `BigInteger#add`.

After this is done, there´s also a `toString(radix)` function for `BigInteger`, where you can display the result for a different radix.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger base = new BigInteger("11000000101010000000000111111111", 2);
    BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1", 2);
    BigInteger result = base.add(one);
    System.out.println(result.toString(2));
}
```

output

```
11000000101010000000001000000000
```

Comment: thank you @Kevin that's exactly what I'm looking for