# Counting every single letter in an array with ASCII table (Unicode code)

Tags: java, arrays

I am new at Java and I could not understand this structure:

```
public static int[] upperCounter(String str) {
    final int NUMCHARS = 26;
    int[] upperCounts = new int[NUMCHARS];
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            upperCounts[c-'A']++;
    }

    return upperCounts;
}
```

This method works, but what does `list[c-'A']++;` mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4318263/73226

Comment: FYI Putting a `System.out.println("c is " + c + ", c-'a' is " (c-'a'));` before the line in question is something you can try on your own. It's a great way to discover things. Then again, it is probably more work than asking S.O. :)

Comment: `list[c-'A']++` is equal to `list[34]++` because `c = 99` (small `c`) and `A = 65`. Thus, `99 - 65 = 34`.

Comment: I assumed `c` itself as a `char` (sure it was an overlooked).

Answer (score 5):

`c - 'A'` is taking a character in the range `['A' .. 'Z']`, and subtracting `'A'` to create a numerical value in the range `[0 .. 25]` so it can be used as an array index.

`upperCounts[c - 'A']++` increments the occurrence count for the character `c` using its corresponding index `c - 'A'`.

Effectively, the loop is generating an array of character type counts.

Answer (score 3):

It means, that you increment (`++`) value of element at `c - 'A'` index in `list` array.

`c` is variable - number of letter in alphabet

`'A'`refers to the Unicode code point of the letter A (65 decimal). Letter B is 66 decimal etc.

Comment: oh okay, for example: String: "Cihangir"
C=67 A=65 
list[2] means 3rd letter of alphabet.. oh amazing.. then from 0, it goes to 1.. okay thanks ^^ I heard ASCII for the first time.. eyv kamil

Comment: Better to say: `'A'` refers to the **Unicode code point** of the letter A. Let's try not to say "ASCII" anymore. It's a Unicode world.

Answer (score 3):

This is really advanced syntax, let me try to break it down:

```
c - 'a'
```

`c` is an indexed variable from the loop, while `'a'` is a character that has a certain integer value as denoted by the ASCII table. This operation produces an integer result.

```
list[c - 'a']
```

This integer value is then used to interface an `int[]` array getting the nth item in the `list` array, returning an integer result.

```
list[c - 'a']++;
```

The `++` operator adds one to that value.

Answer (score 2):

Value in a `char` variable can be represented as an integer. The letter `A` is `65` and `a` would be `97` (see the [`ASCII` table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for more letters).

```
list[c-'A']++;
```

This code means, take the value of `c` (which is between `65` and `90` [due to `if ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' )`]) and reduce the value of `A` (i.e. `65`). This will return an index in array `list` and increases its current value.

Example: c is `C`:

```
C = 67
A = 65
C - A = 2
```

Therefore index `2` will be changed. Index `2` is the *third* element, like `C` is the *third* letter in the alphabet.