# How do I extract a single digit from an integer

Tags: java

I am currently trying to extract a single digit (int) from a integer (larger than 1 digit) but I have not been able to find any help in this matter.

> E.g:
>
> - get 3 from 123456
>
> **or**
>
> - get 4 from 1257848

**How would I do this in Java?**

Comment: `x = (int)123456/10000`?

Comment: Is there a function to do this though? or will division work every time?

Comment: You mean that you're trying to extract a digit from an integer.

Comment: Do you always want to extract the first digit?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean

Comment: either do basic math and  cast to int, or cast to string and use substring operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
String.valueOf(Math.abs((long)x)).charAt(0)
```

or do some calculation like

```
 int x= Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(123456).substring(0, 1));
```

or

```
int digit(int x) {
    while (x > 9) {
        x /= 10;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: @Daedric Appreciate answers, this is a working solution. If you don't want to use Strings, then you'll have to use some maths.

Comment: This would be one solution though, even though the `long` cast isn't needed. This would return an `int`.

Comment: Isnt there a simpler way like getting a character uses a method

Comment: @Daedric:- Added few more approaches. Kindly check.

Comment: @RahulTripathi if the second method works that would be great it is much more appealing.

Answer (score 4):

Use `% or /` operator depending on how many digits you want to extract. Like

```
12345 % 10 = 5

12345 % 100 = 45

12345 / 10000 = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to parse a char, just use [`-'0'` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318263/java-subtract-0-from-char-to-get-an-int-why-does-this-work):

```
int first = String.valueOf(123456).charAt(0) - '0';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int getFirstDigit(int val) {
  if (val < 0) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Bad Input: " + val);
  }
  while (val > 9) {
    val = val / 10;
  }
  return val;
}
```

Comment: This is probably a better solution than the String conversion. This will also work with an `int` of any length. +1 edit: You could just take the absolute value and also process negative integers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the `n`-th (from right to left) digit (the counting is 0-based in my example) you just need to calculate `(num/(10^n))%10`.

Let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public int getVal(int digits)
{
  String str=String.valueOf(digits);
  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
     {
       if((str.charAt(i)) == '3') // 3 or 4 or whatever digit you desire
         return str.charAt(i);
     }
  return 0;
}
```