# How to give input array[] using scanner without space?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

In this below program, I'm trying to check whether the number is ISBN or not.  I'm giving input with spaces (eg: `0 3 0 6 4 0 6 1 5 2`) because array only accepts it like this. I don't know how to give input without space to read.  Can anyone help me how to read the number eg: 0306406152 and also it will read 10 numbers only like if(i==10) else it says it's not ISBN number to give output.

```
public class ISBN {

    int digits[];
    int dig = 11;
    int sum;
    int isbn1;

    public void CheckISBN() {
        for (int digit : digits) {
            // System.out.println(digit);
            if (dig >= 1) {
                dig--;
                digit = digit * dig;
                // System.out.println(dig);
            }
            sum = sum + digit;
            isbn1 = sum % 11;
        }
        if (isbn1 == 0) {
            System.out.println(isbn1);
            System.out.println("it's valid ISBN number");
        } else {
            System.out.println("sorry it's not valid ISBN");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ISBN aa = new ISBN();
        aa.digits = new int[10];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            aa.digits[i] = scan.nextInt();

            i++;
            if (i == 10) // aa.CheckISBN();
            {
                break;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < aa.digits.length; j++) {
                // System.out.print(aa.digits[j]);
            }
            //System.out.println();
        }
        aa.CheckISBN();
    }
}
```

`SAMPLE OUTPUT`: 0 3 0 6 4 0 6 1 5 2
 it's valid ISBN number

Comment: why don't you take input in string rather than using array ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your sample output and actual output are completely different. You don't even print the isbn in your output

Comment: `Scanner` depends on whitespace to delimit tokens, so `hasNextXXX` works properly.  Without spaces, your ISBN is basically a valid integer.  Using a `Pattern` with a regex would be better for pattern-matching.

Answer (score 0):

When the number is given without spaces,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ISBN {

    int digits[];
    int dig = 11;
    int sum;
    int isbn1;

    public void CheckISBN() {

        if(this.digits.length != 10)
        {
            System.out.println("sorry it's not valid ISBN");
            return;
        }

        for (int digit : digits) {
            // System.out.println(digit);
            if (dig >= 1) {
                dig--;
                digit = digit * dig;
                // System.out.println(dig);
            }
            sum = sum + digit;
            isbn1 = sum % 11;
        }
        if (isbn1 == 0) {
            //System.out.println(isbn1);
            System.out.println("it's valid ISBN number");
        } else {
            System.out.println("sorry it's not valid ISBN");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ISBN aa = new ISBN();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String num = scan.next(); //take input as a string
        int[] digits = new int[num.length()]; 

        for(int i = 0; i<digits.length; i++)
            digits[i] = num.charAt(i) - '0';

        aa.digits = digits;

        aa.CheckISBN();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can accept the answer, if you think it answered your question

Comment: yes, and can you explain this stmt please `digits[i] = num.charAt(i) - '0';`

Comment: `num` is of type `String`. Strings are made of `chars`. We take the `char` at index `i` and convert it to an integer to put to `digit` array. How converstion occur is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318263/java-subtract-0-from-char-to-get-an-int-why-does-this-work).

Answer (score 0):

Or scan it as `int` to get number format validation for free:

```
public class ISBN {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            checkISBN(scan.nextInt());
        }
    }

    public static void checkISBN(int isbn) {
        int sum = sum(digits(isbn));
        int isbn1 = sum % 11;
        if (isbn1 == 0) {
            System.out.println(isbn1);
            System.out.println("it's valid ISBN number");
        } else {
            System.out.println("sorry it's not valid ISBN");
        }
    }

    private static int sum(int[] digits) {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, digits.length)
                .map(i -> i * digits[digits.length - i])
                .sum();
    }

    private static int[] digits(int isbn) {
        return Integer.toString(isbn)
                .chars()
                .map(c -> c - '0')
                .toArray();
    }
}
```

N.B.: It works for ISBN both with or without leading zeros.