# Strange loop behavior in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm a java learner and I have a task to do from a forum to learn more.
The challenge is receive a number and multiply it by it's own digit like:

input `999`

output `9*9*9 = 729 then 7*2*9 =126 again 1*2*6 = 12 finally 1*2=2 until it hits only one single digit.

I got this issue which I ask a variable to add the multiplication of an array of length of 2 it returns me this

```
 1------------------1
 49-----------------2 
 final result 2450
```

And this is the code..

```
class Persist {
  public static void persistence(long n) {
     String number = String.valueOf((int)n);
     char[] digits1 = number.toCharArray();
     int value = 1;

     for(int i = 0 ;i <= digits1.length -1;i++) {
        System.out.println(value + "-----------------" + digits1[i]);
        value = value* (int)digits1[i];
     }

     System.out.println((int)value);
 }

 public static void main(String [] args) {
    persistence(12);
 }
}
```

I can try to fix this but I'm interested to know whats wrong.Thank you all in advanced for the help and just by passing by.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Subtract '0' from char to get an int... why does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318263/java-subtract-0-from-char-to-get-an-int-why-does-this-work)

Comment: You can avoid all that conversion. Hint: `1234 % 10 = 4` and `1234 / 10 = 123`.

Comment: You wrote "input 999 output 9*9*9 = 81".  But 9*9 = 81, and 9*9*9 = 729, right?  Could you correct your question?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the ASCII values of the numbers (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) i.e. 1=49 and 2=50

49 * 50 = 2450

You can use the Character.getNumericValue to get the numerical value of the char instead, i.e.

```
class Persist {
    public static void persistence(long n) {
        String number = String.valueOf((int)n);
        char[] digits1 = number.toCharArray();
        int value = 1;
        for(int i = 0 ;i <= digits1.length -1;i++) {
            System.out.println(value + "-----------------" + digits1[i]);
            value = value* Character.getNumericValue((int)digits1[i]);

        }
        System.out.println((int)value);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        persistence(12);

    }
```

Comment: Avoids "magic" numbers -- good

Comment: Umm, actually, [getNumericValue(char ch)
Returns the int value that the specified _Unicode_ character represents.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char-)

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest to understand if you look at the values with a debugger. During the actual calculation `value = value * (int)digits1[i]` you are not using the value of the digits but the ASCII value of the chars. This is 1->49 and 2->50 so you are calculating 49*50=2450.
Change the line to `value = value* Character.getNumericValue(digits1[i]);` and you get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this. I adjusted it so that a 0 value digit is converted to 1. You can comment that out (did this because any digit of 0 turns the answer into 0). This version will keep re-multiplying until it's down to one digit.

```
public class Persist {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int answer = persistence(234);
        System.out.println("        length: " + String.valueOf(answer).length());
        while (  String.valueOf(answer).length() > 1)   {   
            answer = persistence(answer);
        } }

    static int persistence(int n) {
        int value = 1;
        String myStr = String.valueOf(n);
        int myStrLen = myStr.length();
        int[] finalIntAr = new int[myStrLen];                                               

        for (int v=0; v< myStrLen;  v++) {
            String subS= myStr.substring(v,v+1);
            System.out.println("the char/int : " + subS);
            Integer bigI = Integer.valueOf(subS);
            if (bigI == 0) { bigI = 1; }   // take this out if you want 0 to perform as 0
            finalIntAr[v] = bigI.intValue();
        }

        for (int i = 0 ;   i < myStrLen;  i++) {
            System.out.println("   -----     first=  " +  value + "  multiplied by : " + finalIntAr[i]);
            value = value * finalIntAr[i];
        }
        System.out.println("\n CURRENT FINAL VALUE *** : " + value);
        return value;
    } }
```

Output:

```
the char/int : 2
the char/int : 3
the char/int : 4
   -----     first=  1  multiplied by : 2
   -----     first=  2  multiplied by : 3
   -----     first=  6  multiplied by : 4

 CURRENT FINAL VALUE *** : 24
        length: 2
the char/int : 2
the char/int : 4
   -----     first=  1  multiplied by : 2
   -----     first=  2  multiplied by : 4

 CURRENT FINAL VALUE *** : 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody posted an answer using no strings or chars, I will. Technically not an answer to your question, though.

```
public static void persistence(long x)
{
    long answer = 1;
    while (x != 0) {
        long onesDigit = x % 10;
        answer *= onesDigit;
        x /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```