# postfix evaluation calculated result is wrong

Tags: java, stack, postfix-notation

I'm trying to implement postfix evaluation using stack, but the result after calculation is not correct, I cannot figure out which part makes the calculation wrong, thanks a lot.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class PostFixEvaluate {
    public static float calculate(Float operand_1,char operator,Float operand_2 ){
        switch(operator){
            case '+':
                return operand_2 + operand_1;

            case '-':
                return operand_2 - operand_1;

            case '*':
                return operand_2 * operand_1;

            case '/':
                return operand_2 / operand_1;
        }

        return 0;
    }   //end calculate()

    public static float postFixEvaluation(String expr){
        Stack<Float> stack = new Stack<>();
        int index = 0;

        while(index < expr.length()){
            char token = expr.charAt(index);
            boolean x = isOperand(token);

            if(x == true){     //operand
                float operandIn = (float)token;
                stack.push(operandIn);
            }
            else{           //operator
                float a = stack.pop();   //operand_1
                float b = stack.pop();   //operand_2
                char w = token;         //operator
                stack.push(calculate(a, w, b));
            }
            index += 1;
        }   //end while

        float result = stack.pop();
        return result;
     }  //postFixEvaluation()

    /*Operand or operator? operator return 1, operand return 2*/
     public static boolean isOperand(char c){
        switch(c){
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
                return false;   //an operator
            default:
                return true;   //an operand
        }   //end switch()
    }  //end isOperand()
}
```

After entering the postfix "312*+456*+97-/+", the result is 3958.0, which is expected to be 22.0, That is much more than wrong but I still cannot figure out why the result is 3958.0.

Comment: As an aside `boolean x = isOperand(token);if(x == true){` would be a lot more readable and less bug-prone as `if(isOperand(token)){`

Comment: use `Character.digit(token, 10)` to *convert* a `char` into the corresponding numeric value

Comment: @user16320675 I converted the CHAR token to FLOAT by using the Character.digit(char, radix) you just recommended, but the result became 2.875, which is still wrong. I'm wondering if the problem occurs at the calculate logic or stack.pop() logic.

Comment: maybe better use a debugger ... I get 22.00 using copy&pasted code after including `digit(token, 10)` - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwozP.png) || but the answer below should work the same

Comment: @user16320675 Maybe it's because I added the function in a wrong place? I added 
`float operandIn = Character.digit(token, 10);` right before
`stack.push(operandIn);` in the if statement.

Comment: @user16320675 Hold on a second... After 5 minutes modified nothing at my code, now the result becomes 22.00... Another mysterious event happened in the IDE. Thank you so much sir for helping me resolve the problem!!!

Comment: ( you cannot mix my solution with the one of Frederico's answer - either one works, but not both together - `digit(token, 10) == (token - '0')` for the usual digits 0-9 )

Answer (score 0):

`char token = expr.charAt(index);` returns `'3'` on the first iteration, but that's a `char` representing the character `'3'` (i.e. 51), not the number 3.

To use the number instead of the character representing that number you can push it into the stack [by subtracting `'0'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318263/java-subtract-0-from-char-to-get-an-int-why-does-this-work) from it, like this:

```
stack.push(operandIn - '0');
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I did see someone on GFG add that line, but after I typed that line, the result is 2.875, which is still wrong.

Comment: Weird, when I ran that I got 22.0